# How to show part of buffer in different buffer?

Tags: buffers, window, narrowing

I have a buffer with some data. I want to select part of buffer and open the selection in different buffer (and window) to make it easier to read for me. Is there some function that does it?

I am looking for something like `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window`, but for selection, not a whole buffer.

Comment: `narrow-to-region` ... and if you like using `org-mode`, there are some `narrow-to-subtree...` functions.  The code behind the scenes use that all the time to limit the scope of the buffer that is being operated on.   And, when you are done, you can `widen` and/or exit the indirect buffer.

Comment: @lawlist Why did you write that in comment question? It looks like a valid answer.

Comment: I generally write comments instead of answers because it's quick (and I'm usually just in between projects, such as compiling something with a minute or two of down-time to see the latest activity on the net) ... it looks like Drew has it covered.  :)

Comment: @lawlist But I want to upvote you, since it helps me and I don't have to download anything else!

Comment: Could you please try `jac.el` available [at github](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/jac/blob/master/jac.el)? After installing `jac.el` you just need the command `jac` to clone the current buffer. The advantage of `jac` is that it only synchronizes text but no text properties. `font-lock` should work in both buffers independently.

Answer (score 4):

See library [Narrow Indirect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NarrowIndirect) (code: [`narrow-indirect.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/narrow-indirect.el)).

It lets you create an indirect buffer that is a clone of the current buffer and that is narrowed to a particular portion of it.

Such an indirect buffer gives you a different view of a portion of the buffer, or even of the whole buffer (use `C-x h C-x 4 n n`). It always has the same text and text properties, but otherwise it is pretty independent.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [edit-indirect](https://github.com/Fanael/edit-indirect).

It lets you create an completely independent buffer which might use a different major-mode, too. You can edit this buffer and commit you changes back to the original buffer when done.